# Can't run mosfets in one leg configuration with ACPL 337J optocoupler

Tags: mosfet, ltspice, mosfet-driver, gate-driving

I am working with a four pin MOSFET(C3M0030090K). You can find the datasheet [here](https://www.wolfspeed.com/media/downloads/1185/C3M0030090K.pdf). The gate driver which I am using is ACPL 337J [(datasheet here)](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/678/V02-4390EN_DS_ACPL-337J_2014-05-09-909393.pdf). The mosfets are in one leg configuration like this:

[image: One_leg_configuration].

Schematic:-

[image: sch]

I am getting the output at load resistance
[image: output].

However, I am also getting a similar pulse at gate of M1(The blue one is for gate and the black one is for load resistance.)

[image: plots]

(How should I attach the schematic and library files?(via google drive or mediafire or what?))

Please suggest any edits in the circuit.

Comment: Please post the schematic in your question. We shouldn't have to download a ZIP file (risky) and unpack it just to understand your question. Make it easy for those you are asking to help you.

Comment: @Transistor I understand your concern. Since the schematic is large(and messy), I will upload some pics making it easy for you to understand.

Comment: There is no detailed description of the problem

Comment: @Transistor please suggest some edits in the circuit. Also if I want to share the schematic and library files, how can I share them?